# Simulating Camera Movement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, simulation, camera-calibration

We have a camera installed in a street in height 5 meters from the ground. A plane can be fitted to all buildings in each left and right side of the street. Assume these planes are perpendicular to the ground and parallel to the street road. Also, assume in the camera coordinate system, x axis is perpendicular to buildings in the right side of the street, y axis is parallel to the street road, and hence z axis is upward perpendicular to the ground.
Assume we have a segmentation method to robustly segment an image to four regions sky, ground, left wall, and right wall. We want to descend the camera for 2 meters to height 3 meters from the ground. Given an image I taken at the original location in height 5, synthesize a new image J using contents of I as if it has been taken from height 3 meters from ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [3D projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) between 2 coordinate spaces (camera and world) and obtain a **view matrix** which will represent the transformation of your view after the translation on y axis.

Since there is no rotation involved, your task should not be so hard.
Here are the steps you should follow:

- Set up the camera space by positioning and orienting the camera and derive a matrix from it(camera space)
- Construct a matrix that maps from world space(you already have) into camera space
- Map given vertexes(your image pixel positions here) from world space to camera space
- Translate those positions using the translation matrix

In your case this should be:

```
       [ 1  0  0 ]  # notice that y axis is
T =    [ 0 -2  0 ]  # translated while the 
       [ 0  0  1 ]  # other two stay the same
```

- Map the translated points back into the world space and enjoy your new view

This link is useful http://schabby.de/view-matrix/ but you can also find a lot of other similar resources explaining the process. It's probably already in your reference text book for this particular class you are taking.